# Bypassing HTML5 Offline Appcache

Tags: html, offline

Is it possible to tell your HTML5 Webapp to not load the site from the appcache, if the client has network connection?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly what you're asking, but a way to achieve this is to set up a `FALLBACK` from `/` to for example `/offline/index.html` and then check in the offline `index.html` if you're online and if you are redirect back to `/`. That way your normal site is loaded over the internet and your offline version is loaded only when offline.

```
FALLBACK:
/ /offline/index.html

NETWORK:
*
```

PS. I have never tried this exact setup, and never even used FALLBACK urls, however I worked a lot with appcaches, so I am pretty sure this should work.